# Correlation failed in IdentityServer4 in docker container behind nginx

Tags: identityserver4

I've got an issue where I'm deploying IdentityServer behind nginx using Docker and I'm experiencing redirect loops. I'm doing this on my own setup, not a cloud provider. The process works fine locally, but once deployed to production where nginx is providing TLS offloading, the process gets stuck in a loop. I've been all over the internet trying to figure this out, have modified my nginx configuration extensively to try and get this working, have incorporated ForwardedHeaders (including the reverse proxy IP, both v4 and v6 because kestrel is setting up on ipv6) and have spent a good bit of time investigating. I took a look at IdentityServer's code and I believe although it isn't IDS4's fault, I think it's skipping over a piece of code for some unknown reason.

The logs indicate that while I'm being redirected after login, the server requesting authentication from IDS4 was unable to locate the AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc cookie.

I took a look at the traffic that happens locally and through nginx with both Fiddler and Wireshark. They both report drastically different behavior between the two sites right after logging in. When working with the localhost version, which again works perfectly, it submits a POST to http://localclient/signin-oidc with the following cookies:

.AspNetcore.Antiforgery.<...>

.AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc.<...>

.AspNetCore.Identity.Application

.AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce

I'm not sure how, because no response prior sets these cookies, but I'm just going to accept it as is for now because it works. On the other hand, the public facing version submits a POST to https://publicclient/signin-oidc with no cookies whatsoever. Upon seeing this, we get redirected back to https://publicIDS4/connect/authorize. Then it just goes in a loop between those two.

Some additional info. When running on localhost and comparing verbose log messages against production's, I see three log messages that are missing when running in production. These messages are:

1) Augmenting SignInContext
RequestPath: /connect/authorize/callback
SourceContext: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService

2) Performing protect operation to key {3a209bdd-eeac-42c0-b8a0-f8c26c952728} with purposes ('STS.Identity', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Identity.Application', 'v2').
RequestPath: /connect/authorize/callback
SourceContext: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector

3) AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
RequestPath: /connect/authorize/callback
SourceContext: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler

These log messages happen prior to the postback to my client server's /signin-oidc url. I have a certificate being loaded up for token signing that I self-signed and IDS4 did not complain.

Do anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: When the correlation cookie is set do the properties differ between environments? I’m thinking maybe nginx may be interfering with the samesite settings - this resulting in the cookie not being transmitted in a request originated from another origin.

Comment: if your problem is switching from https to http, try to add  `app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
               // if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SSL_OFFLOAD") == "true")
                    {context.Request.Scheme = "https";}

                return next();
            });` to your `Startup.Configure()`